# Apache Tomcat v8 server cannot auto load library to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

After I setup the Apache Tomcat v8 server inside eclipse, when I create a new project, it not automatically load the lib for it, such as servlet-api.jar, is there possible to import it by build path? or anyone encounter this issue before? I don't want import manually each time I create a new project.

Comment: How dod you "setup" the server inside Eclipse? Using a Dynamic Web Project?

Comment: @nitind my project is setup using dynamic web project, my server was add by runtime environments

Comment: Technically Tomcat 8 isn't finished yet, and the Web Tools Platform doesn't have full support for it. Setting the server runtime to the project should have added its libraries, including the Servlet API, to the Java Build Path. Are you saying you can't code against the APIs (you get compiler failures and no content assist), or that the servlet-api jar isn't physically in the project?